# Unresolved Externals

Tags: c++, linker

I am working on a simple top down shooter and wanted to move my ships to a separate ShipManager class, where I can manage all of them from a single location. However, upon starting this I get a linker error on my playerShip:

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class Ship * ShipManager::playerShip"

ShipManager.h looks like this:

```
class Ship;

class ShipManager
{
public:
static Ship*    playerShip;
};
```

I have nothing in the ShipManager .cpp yet. What am I missing? The only other place I use this code is in my game class where I am actually calling ShipManager::playerShip, and I don't get any errors there.

I include "ShipManager.h" in my game.cpp, so it should find it right? I have a feeling I'm forgetting something simple in this class.

Comment: The C++ SOFAQ answers this question: http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/faq#toc4

Answer (score 6):

Static members have to be defined somewhere. You are declaring `playerShip`, but not defining it. You need to add somewhere, *necessarily and only one cpp file*:

```
Ship* ShipManager::playerShip;
```

Comment: *"preferably on a cpp file"* should be *"necessarily and only one cpp file"*, defining it in on a header file would eventually break the One Definition Rule.

Answer (score 4):

You only declared the static member, you also need to define it in (only)one of your cpp files:

```
Ship* ShipManager::playerShip;
```

**Good Read:**
[What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)